# Trim Spaces in a String

Tags: sql-server

UserId should be like 'keerthi.ks' in the database.

But in some tables some data is like 'keerthi .ks'

Need to clear the middle spaces.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Use the `REPLACE` function with update to remome unwanted spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to replace the space by nothing.

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

More info here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT REPLACE('keerthi .ks',' ','')
```

Note, this will remove all the space in the text

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
SELECT REPLACE('keerthi .ks', ' ', '')
```

You can also use column name instead of hard coded value.